# Fourier series of a complicated function

Tags: fourier-series

I am looking for a Fourier series of the following function:

$g(x) = D\sin(C\arctan( Bx - E(Bx - \arctan(Bx)))) + A $

What mathematical software did you use to find the series?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried wolfram alpha or mathematica? If there's a closed form for the integral these should find it...

Comment: @danimal free version of wolfram alpha takes too long